# How can I copy structure of mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database

I have developed new feature for my website on my PC that involves updating some of the table structures, Is there any way that I can update my website database with the changes I made on my local machine without losing any data on remote machine?
The database I am running my website on is "mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.16, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper"

Comment: You can take a look at an [old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295312/difference-between-two-mysql-databases-which-are-on-two-different-remote-machine/17298414#17298414) for a PHP script that will compare the structure of two MySQL databases. From there you can use something like phpMyAdmin to manually update the production database with the changes.

Answer (score 0):

first take a backup of remote database.

then come to local mechine and create a backup into a sql file which part newly develop by [mysql-workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)
tool and this sql file run into remote.

then all new table are update in remote without data loss..

if any error then run the remote backup file..

Comment: Depending on how the backup was created, this will either fail (because the table structure doesn't match), or will overwrite production data with test data from the local system.

Comment: dont make all table backup from local database . only create a backup which table create newly without data and run it remotely

Comment: Which won't help if the structure of any of the existing tables was changed.

Comment: i think it would not possible

Comment: just example you have existing table that have column is not unic in remote.but you change it localy that column type unic.if remote table have some data then it conflit when you upgrade changes in existing table.